# How to listen to callback of a DialogFragment using Views in a ComposeView of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

In a ComposeView in a Fragment, can not listen to callback from a DialogFragment using Views

I'm try to using compose in a project that most screen using Views.
In a fragment I created a Compose View, and show a Dialog Fragment

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyScreen()
            }

        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyScreen() {
         LoginAlertDialog(LocalContext.current as Activity).show(){
            EventBus.getDefault().sendEvent(MyEvent())
       }
}
```

My LoginAlertDialog is just a fragment with views

```
class LoginAlertDialog(activity: Activity) : AlertDialog.Builder(activity) {

    private lateinit var binding: CustomAlertBinding

    fun show(isMain: Boolean, onDismiss: () -> Unit){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
            .create()
        val inflater = (activity).layoutInflater
        binding = CustomAlertBinding.inflate(inflater)
        builder.setView(binding.root)
        builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        builder.show()

        binding.cancel.setOnClickListener {
             onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

But onDismiss() is not fired when I click cancel.
What I did wrong and how can I listen to onDismiss() inside a Compose

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following: you are successfully executing the `onDismiss`, which is sending that event through the event bus, but you are **NOT** dismissing the actual dialog.

To do that just add the line `builder.dismiss()` to the click listener you have on the cancel button, so it becomes like the following:

```kotlin
class LoginAlertDialog(activity: Activity) : AlertDialog.Builder(activity) {

    private lateinit var binding: CustomAlertBinding

    fun show(isMain: Boolean, onDismiss: () -> Unit){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
            .create()
        val inflater = (activity).layoutInflater
        binding = CustomAlertBinding.inflate(inflater)
        builder.setView(binding.root)
        builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        builder.show()

        binding.cancel.setOnClickListener {
             builder.dismiss()
             onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```